# Removing Non-English Words from CSV - NLTK

Tags: pandas, nlp, nltk

I am relatively new to Python and NLTK and have a hold of Flickr data stored in CSV and want to remove non-english words from the tags column. I keep getting errors saying "expected a String or a byte-like object". I have a feeling it's to do with the fact the tags column is in a Pandas Series datatype currently and not a String. However, none of the related solutions I've seen on Stack have worked when it comes to converting to string.

I have this code:

```
#converting pandas df to string
filtered_new = df_filtered_english_only.applymap(str)

#check it's converted to string
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype
is_string_dtype(filtered_new['tags'])

filtered_new['tags'].dropna(inplace=True)
tokens = filtered_new['tags'].apply(word_tokenize)

#print(tokens)

#remove non-English tags
#initialise corpus of englihs word from nltk
words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())
" ".join(w for w in nltk.word_tokenize(df_filtered_english_only["tags"]) \
         if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally: You should give an example of your dataset.

What is the previous content of the column "tags"? How are tags separated? How is "no tags" expressed and is there a difference between "empty list" and "NAN"?

I assume tags can contain multiple words so that is important, also when it comes to removing non-english words.

But for simplicity sake let's assume there are only one-word-tags and they are separated by a whitespace, so that each rows content is a string. Also let's assume that empty rows (no tags) have the default NA value for pandas (`numpy.NaN`). And since you probably read the file with pandas some values might have been auto-converted to numbers.

Setup:

```
import numpy
import pandas
import nltk

df = pandas.DataFrame({"tags": ["bird dog cat xxxyyy", numpy.NaN, "Vogel Hund Katze xxxyyy", 123]})
>                       tags
  0      bird dog cat xxxyyy
  1                      NaN
  2  Vogel Hund Katze xxxyyy
  3                      123
```

Drop NA rows and tokenize:

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
tokens = df["tags"].astype(str).apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
> 0        [bird, dog, cat, xxxyyy]
  2    [Vogel, Hund, Katze, xxxyyy]
  3                           [123]
  Name: tags, dtype: object
```

Filter by known words, always allow non-alpha:

```
words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())
filtered = [" ".join(w for w in row if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha()) for row in tokens]
> ['bird dog cat', '', '123']
```

The main problem in your code probably results from you doing a flat iteration over a nested list (you already tokenized so now each row in the pandas Series is a list). If you modify the iteration to be nested as well as I did in the example the code should run.

Also you should never do string conversion (be it `.astype(str)` or any other way) BEFORE removing NAs because then NAs will become something like `'nan'` and will not be removed. First drop NA to handle empty cells, then convert to handle other stuff like numbers etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - I've also posted something below in the hope you may be able to also shed light on the code a bit more? Many thanks.

Comment: I've redirected the further question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72015653/removing-custom-defined-words-from-list-python