# Removing Custom-Defined Words from List - Python

Tags: python, list, filter

I have a dataframe column that looks like:

[image]

I'm looking into removing special characters. I' hoping to attach the tags (in list of lists) so that I can append the column to an existing df.

This is what I gathered so much, but it doesn't seem to work. Regex in particular is causing me so much pain as it always returns "expected string or byte-like objects".

```
df = pd.read_csv('flickr_tags_participation_inequality_omit.csv')
#df.dropna(inplace=True) and tokenise
tokens = df["tags"].astype(str).apply(nltk.word_tokenize)

filter_words = ['.',',',':',';','?','@','-','...','!','=', 'edinburgh', 'ecosse', 'écosse', 'scotland']
filtered = [i for i in tokens if i not in filter_words]
#filtered = [re.sub("[.,!?:;-=...@#_]", '', w) for w in tokens]
#the above line didn't work


tokenised_tags= []
for i in filtered:
    tokenised_tags.append(i) #this turns the single lists of tags into lists of lists
print(tokenised_tags)
```

The above code doesn't remove the custom-defined stopwords.

Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hi! COuld you please hardcode your dataframe into your code, for instance with something like `df = pd.DataFrame('column1': [...], 'column2': [...], ...)`? We don't have access to your csv file.

Comment: What is the exact problem? Removing tokens that are equal to `filter_words`? Or do you want to remove special chars from all tokens in the `tokens` list?

Comment: Does `filtered = [[t for t in tok_sent if t not in filter_words] for tok_sent in tokens]` work as you need?

Comment: Did that help? If not, please provide 1) **text** input, 2) expected respected output.

Comment: Sorry, new to Stack so appreciate the comments and advice. The issue I'm having is to do with the above code not actually filtering out the words in `filter_words` . The dataframe is as: `df = pd.DataFrame('ID': 1, 'tags': 'flower red bus ecosse')` for illustration.

Comment: UPDATE: It works, thank you so much! I wondered, currently I have it as a list of list, I want to attach that back to the dataframe, I thought this would just be a simple case of this: `df.append(pd.DataFrame(tokenised_tags, columns=df.columns))`. but I am having no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```py
df['filtered'] = df['tags'].apply(lambda x: [t for t in nltk.word_tokenize(x) if t not in filter_words])
```

Note that `nltk.word_tokenize(x)` outputs a list of strings so you can apply a regulat list comprehension to it.

Comment: I have another related question, which I try to use the code inspired from yourself, however no luck. Wondered whether you would be able to have a look at this, cheers! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72091967/removing-custom-defined-words-from-list-part-ii-python